# Spring securtiy Acl throwing nullpointer on addPermission

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spring-security-acl

I am using Springsecurity-ACL-2.0-RC1 and webflow 2.0.8.1

So when calling my Service to addPermission via:

```
service.addPermission(domainobject, username, permission)
```

which basically is:

```
void addPermission(def domainobject, String username,
                   Permission permission) {
    aclUtilService.addPermission domainobject.class, domainobject.id, username, permission

}
```

I will get a NullPointer:

```
    ERROR builder.ClosureInvokingAction  - Exception occured invoking flow action: Cannot get property 'className' on null object
Message: Cannot get property 'className' on null object
    Line | Method
->>  263 | createAcl              in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.jdbc.GormAclLookupStrategy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    229 | doCall                 in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.jdbc.GormAclLookupStrategy$_convertEntries_closure4
|    228 | convertEntries . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.jdbc.GormAclLookupStrategy
|    146 | lookupObjectIdentities in     ''
|    107 | doCall . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.jdbc.GormAclLookupStrategy$_readAclsById_closure1
|     76 | readAclsById           in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.jdbc.GormAclLookupStrategy
|    288 | readAclsById . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.AclService
|    268 | readAclById            in     ''
|    259 | readAclById . . . . .  in     ''
|    177 | updateAcl              in     ''
|     90 | addPermission . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.AclUtilService
|     55 | addPermission          in     ''
```

Well I basically have tried to rewrite my service, based on the Tutorial/Example-Application - even used the code from them with basically no result.

So I am running out of ideas on how to fix it, I am thinking about removing the webflows, and simply build this flow on my own.

Thank you
Simon

PS: This is my first entry on stackoverflow, so if I have missed crucial information just tell me, I will add it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

looks like youre not passing a Domainobject

```
Domainobject foo = bar


service.addPermission(foo, username, permission)
```

Comment: based on intellij idea debugging and println before addpermission i do!